# The constructor ExitAd (new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined

Tags: java, android

So, I have this exit ad, which goes in @Override backpress method:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
      ExitAd exit = new ExitAd(this);
          exit.show();
    super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

That works fine, but I have to disable back button in my app, and only use the exit button I have made. So I tried to place this code in my exit button, which is in my InnitializeVars() method (I call this method in my onCreate method):

```
public void innitializeVars() {

        exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bexit);

        exit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ExitAd exit = new ExitAd(this);
                exit.show();
                finish();

            }
        });


    }
```

But it didn't work, I get the error from the beggining of the thread.

Comment: If should be `ExitAd exit = new ExitAd(YourActivity.this);`

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how I missed that.